What is the significance of a set having an accumulation point in a topoogical space? (Application of topology to analysis)
The identity theorem of complex analysis relates to the extrapolation of the equality of two complex functions between domains. In the statement, it is required that one domain have atleast one  accumulation point in the other for this statement to work.
I am  aware of density and it's multipile uses in analysis. A subset $S$ of topological space $X$ is said to be dense in the aforementioned space, if for every open set about any point in $x$, there is a non empty intersection with the subset $S$. This is quite a strong fact, as it means all points of $X$ can be approximated through $S$.
An example of this idea being realized in Analysis can be seen in the following:

Stone Weierstraß theorem: Every continous function can be approximated by a polynomial

Measure Theory (Indirectly): Every continous function can be approximated by a sum of simple functions Refer

Transfering countability of basis in a metric space: If we have that $S$ is a countable set, then we can prove that we can find a countable basis for $X$ through application of density.


These facts stem from the idea that we can approximate any point in X  in a topological sense through points of $S$.
I think maybe a way to think about only a single accumulation point is to consider it as flipping the script. This one accumulation point can act as a stand in for the entire set $S$ when discussing it's properties in $X$.
I'm trying to understand, what is the topological significance(/implication) of having a single accumulation point? Or perhaps, explain how it is useful in putting various proofs?

As I understand it, mainly you want to ensure that any intersection between the domain is not just an isolated point, which does not provide much information on the function. Accumulation point is just saying you can have a sequence of points from one domain approximating the other domain, without just being a single point in the intersection.
